# Difference over Mapped Network Drive and Network Location

Tags: windows, networking

Is there any major differences over a mapped network location over mapped network drive? Is the only main difference that one gets a drive letter that can be shared.

Comment: If you've got a drive letter, Windows MUST have checked your credentials. But I wouldn't call that a "major difference."

Comment: lots of scripting platforms will recognize z:\ while failing to understand \\server\share\, so network drive mapping allows them to access the files the same way they would if they were on a local drive. Note that many linux's do the same, by mapping a location in the users home to a server share, so that apps don't need to know a thing about samba in order to use files over it.

Comment: Services don't see mapped drives is one difference to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the only difference (as well, a mapped drive will re-establish itself upon login)

```
windows explorer to \\servername\sharedfoldername
```

equals

```
Z: mapped to \\servername\sharedfoldername
```